# trying to understand multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am starting to learn how to use multiprocessing, and, the best to learn is to make some trials and see what happens. So I did, but in my first attempt, I am getting something that I am not sure to understand, so I would appreciate your comments, or your corrections:

So, I did a very easy program, just read a pytable and print the results, depending on a single given parameter:

```
from tables import *
import scipy as sc

def getP(pathToTable, p):

    with openFile(pathToTable,'r') as f:

        tab = f.getNode("/mainTab")
        a = [row['value'] for row in tab.where("(page == p) & (ok == 1)")]   

        print (p, sc.mean(a), sc.std(a))
```

And, to test it, I am doing like this:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>>pags = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> te = 'C:\Desktop\testMultiProc.h5'
>>>import testMp as m
>>> for i in pags:
...     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=m.getP, args=(te,i))
...     p.start()
...     p.join()
...
```

This works, and I am getting the results like this:

```
(1, 9.0953793794588282, 0.33533126564851207)
(2, 9.0871612678994946, 0.33453983570210977)
(3, 9.0466206717415556, 0.32227094723414906)
(4, 9.1115445293825204, 0.32247317223440275)
(5, 9.1731876730458826, 0.33230456228097616)
(6, 8.9801903625732713, 0.32238759095899067)
(7, 9.0102797573336719, 0.34441213144617178)
(8, 8.8340961470191885, 0.32342748738790894)
```

So here come my questions:

If I am not wrong, this is happening simultaneously, then, why I am getting the output in order?? I mean, let's say that for p = 3 the process ends the first because there are few values in the table with p=3, so why I do not get `(3, 9.0466206717415556, 0.32227094723414906)`as the first output for example??

That makes me think that either I am doing it wrong or I do not understand yet what is happening here.

I have selected `pags = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` with an idea in mind....I did that because, first I did:

```
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
8
```

So my idea was to take profit of 8 cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not happening simultaneously because you're calling `join`.

`join` will block until the process has completed.

Effectively:

1. You start a separate process to deal with the first item
2. You wait for that process to complete
3. You start a separate process to deal with the second item
4. You wait for that process to complete
5. ... and so on

You need to drop the `join` call inside that loop. If you want to wait for all the subprocesses to complete, store the result from calling `multiprocessing.Process` and join on those values in a separate loop, something like (untested):

```
processes = []
for i in pags:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=m.getP, args=(te,i))
    p.start()
    processes += [p]

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks Lasse, yeah it sounds actually like I want to achieve, I want all of the processes to start and run on time, in parallel (to save some processing time), but at the end, I want the overall process to wait until all of them have finished before continuig...to be especific....If there is a message `"Job Finished"`at the very end, it must be showed just if all of the 8 or N processes have finished....